# In the figure: prove that $\overline {AM} \perp \overline {DE}$ if $M$ is the middle point on $\overline {BC}$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have this geomtry problem:

Be $\triangle ABC$ a right triangle in $A$, $\overline {AH}$ the altitude over $\overline {BC}$. From $H$ there is a perpendicular $\overline {HE}$ to $\overline {AB}$ and $\overline {HD}$ to $\overline {AC}$. Prove that $\overline {AM} \perp \overline {DE}$ if $M$ is the middle point on $\overline {BC}$.

[image]

I´m having difficulties to prove this. I'd mark every angle that I think I need with numbers to write faster.

My intake so far: try to prove that $7=6=2=8$. Right now I know that $7=8, 6=2$ Because those are opposite on vertex F. Also $1=10$ and $11=5$ by parallels. $3+4=90º$ I know that if $M$ is the middle point to a right triangle then $AM=MC$ and $BC=BM$ making the triangles with two congruent angles. I even try to use exterior angle for the triangles $EFA, AFD$ and $EMF$. But I'm stuck here.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: I aldeary prove that $\overline {AH} = \overline {DE}$. That was the first part of this problem

Comment: is $AH$ the altitude from $A$?

Comment: yeah. It was the first part of the problem. I already solve that part thats why I didn´t include it

Comment: you need to include all the necessary information. Without knowing it's the altitude how are people supposed to solve it?

Comment: Didn't found it useful for the problem...

Comment: There is no way $\overline{AH} \cong \overline{BC}$. Did you mean  $\overline{AH} \perp \overline{BC}$?

Comment: @stevengregory So sry, already fixed. Is the altitude over BC so your statement is correct.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

Join $AH$ and observe that triangles $AHD$ and $AED$ are congruent, but $AHD$ is similar to $ABC$. It follows that $AED$ and $ABC$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Angle 5 is equal to $90 - \angle 4$, because $AEHD$ is a rectangle. Then your conclusion is immediate.

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: $∠5$ is equal to $90-∠10$.

Comment: $90-∠4$ would be true for $\overline {AH}$ not $\overline {AM}$

Comment: $\angle 5$ is equal to $\angle HAD$, which in turn equals to $90-\angle ACH = 90- \angle 4.$ If you don't see that, then I am not sure what else to say.